# BLUETOOTH causing NPE

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I want to use a BLUETOOTH I added this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

next I did this :

```
String uid = "0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(uid.toUpperCase()); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
```

but here ;

```
mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
```

I have this Error

> va.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket  on a null object reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: what is mmsocket? if it is an object than initialize like this,
for ex: Textview text;
and refer id if exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mmDevice` is not instantiated properly, that's why you're getting `NullPointerException`. Prevent this with simple nullcheck: `if(mmDevice!=null)`.

1. Do you ask for permissions at runtime? Since Android M, you should check for permissions from your Activity:

```
private void checkPermissions() {
    ArrayList<String> permissions = ArrayList();
    if (checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        permissions.add(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        permissions.add(BLUETOOTH);
    if (checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        permissions.add(BLUETOOTH_ADMIN);
    if (permissions.isNotEmpty())
        requestPermissions(permissions.toTypedArray(), REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
    else {
    startBluetoothService();
    }
}
```

2. Make sure you instantiate your BluetoothDevice object properly. For that, you should either scan for devices using BluetoothManager:

```
BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.adapter;
//check if bluetooth is enabled 
if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled){
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(); 
    //make sure you register this receiver to properly receive callbacks
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        //Finding devices                 
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            doThingsWithDevice();
    }
  }
}
};
```

or, if you know device `address`, you can use `mBluetoothManager.adapter.getRemoteDevice("deviceAddress")` 
method.